# detect os using jscript

Tags: javascript, linux, unix

When i try below code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>

            var OStype ="Unknown OS";

            if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OStype ="Linux";
            else if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OStype ="Unix";
            else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") != -1) OStype = "MacOS";
            else if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OStype ="Windows";

            alert("OS is :"+OStype);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output is : Unix

But I am using "Linux Ubuntu 12.04", I am getting confuse!

Can anyone explain about this?

Comment: You should read about [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) and [Unix-like operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `navigator` object provides information about the *browser*, not the operating system.  The `appVersion` property provides a small amount of information about the type of OS that the browser was compiled for, but it's not meant to tell you exactly what OS it's running on.

X11 is the windowing system that's typically used on Unix and Linux systems.  It's possible to use X11 on Windows and MacOS too, but that's much less common.  If the `appVersion` contains "X11" then the OS is probably either Unix *or* Linux, but you don't know which.  It'd be more accurate to set `OStype` to "Unix-like" instead of "Unix".

The `navigator.userAgent` property provides more detailed information.  In particular, it actually includes "Linux" when running on Linux.